# Flutter rotated image background color black issue

Tags: flutter, image, dart, rotation

**I'm using this Rotate function in Flutter application but if I use this rotated image the background color will be black but I need the background color in the image to be white.**

```
  Future rotateImage(String imagePath, double rotationValue) async {
    File imageFile = File(imagePath);

    var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    List<int> imageBytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();

    var originalImage = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes));
    
    img.Image fixedImage = img.copyRotate(originalImage!,
            angle: rotationValue, interpolation: img.Interpolation.average);
    
    var fixedFile = await imageFile.writeAsBytes(img.encodePng(
       fixedImage,
     ));


    return fixedFile;
  }
```

[image]

**It would be appreciated if anyone could help me**

Comment: i think this is from you default bg color are you wrapping it with scaffold?

Comment: No i check the image widget it has black background and color does not changed.

Comment: hmm have you tried rotatedbox on this?

Comment: Nope, i need image file after the rotating. I know how to rotate with widgets.